# Array of data format as parameter angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, symfony, form-data

I have a server in Symfony in which I use a function via an AngularJS client. This function requests a data array as a parameter.
Of that type :

```
[nom => test, provenance => test, numero => 12 ]
```

The code obtained with Postman when I test the server:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("form[nom]", "test");
form.append("form[provenance]", "test");
form.append("form[numero]", "12"); 
var settings = {  
  "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/produits",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {    
    "authorization": "ey.....YMpJJA",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "0dd5a3...ad03a6d3"  
  },
    "processData": false,
    "contentType": false,
    "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
    "data": form
} 
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {  
  console.log(response);
});
```

I now try to reproduce the same result but on the side of my application in AngularJS, and send my data via a form in HTML, but the problem is that I can not retrieve my data entered in form.

server side:

```
/**
 * @Route ("/api/produits", name="api_produit_add")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $produit = $this->getProduit();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($benevole, array('csrf_protection' => false))
        ->add('nom', TextType::class, array('required' => true))
        ->add('provenance', TextType::class, array('required' => true))
        ->add('numero', TextType::class, array('required' => true))
        ->getForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));

        if ($form->isValid() && sizeof($request->request->get('ingroupe'))) {
            $produit->setPass(sha1($form->getData()->getPass()));
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
            return new JsonResponse('ok');
        } else {
            $errors = [];
            foreach ($form->getErrors(true, true) as $error) {
                $errors[] = $error->getOrigin()->getName() . ' : ' . $error->getMessage();
            }
            $response = new JsonResponse($errors);
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
            return $response;
        }
    }

    $response = new JsonResponse('only POST method');
    $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    return $response;

}
```

For the moment this is what I could do on the side of my application:

```
var add = function(form){
var token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
var formdata = new FormData();
for (var key in form) {
    console.log(key, form[key]);
    formdata.append(key, form[key]);
}
    $ionicLoading.show();
    return $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : API_ENDPOINT.url + '/produits',
            data    : formdata,
            transformRequest: angular.indentity,
            headers : {Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token,'Content-Type': undefined, 'Accept': 'application/json' },
       }).then(function(result) {
            console.dir(result.data);
    },function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
     });
};
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.add = function () {
    console.log($scope.form);
    LoginService.edit($scope.form).then(function(response){
        //success callback
        console.log(response);
        //do something with the data
    },function(response){
        //error callback
    });
};
```

So I was wondering how to transform exactly what I send in the format requested by the server.

Which returns me this in the request Payload:
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nom"

But the format I'm looking for is:
Content-Disposition: form-data; **name = "form[nom]"**
 
I'm on course of ideas..si someone could help me please ^^

Comment: Why is this question tagged `angularjs`? There is no Angular code here.

Comment: What are you getting for data on the server? What are you using to get that data? Can you update your question with that information

Comment: The question has been edited, I hope I was able to give more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the result you are looking for you should do this:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
for (var key in form) {
    console.log(key, form[key]);
    formdata.append('form['+key+']', form[key]);
}
```

I hope it will help you